# Display cells while others load in the UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Right now my table view presents 5 cells at the same time. I load them all up into an array so the "flow" of the UITableView is easier. But since there quite a few objects, the initial load can take quite a bit.

So my question is, is there a way to present the initial 5-7 cells while the rest are loading? Or what would be the practice for this?

The idea: for the first few cells to come up as fast possible, even while we are loading a bunch in the background so the user isn't sitting there waiting for 100+ cells to load.

Also, I am loading this cells with parse (I am getting the user's info including an image).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This may not work depending on where your data comes from and when it gets into your app, but this is what I would do. Allow your array to fill up with the first 5-7 items. Then call reloadData on your table view. Assuming your datasource is hooked up to your array properly, it will load the first few items. Then let your array continue to load until it's complete, and call reloadData again. You could even use this strategy repetitively to continually load new data. Good luck!

Comment: I actually did that ha. I reloaded the table data after the "count" was 7, but it doesn't really reload it...it keeps on loading the rest of the items.

I am guessing it is because the query is running in the main thread maybe?